# Is there a way to get the file opened in VLC with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, vlc

I want to get the full name of file that opened in VLC now.

I have only found out this:

```
tell application "VLC"
    set current_file to name of first window
end tell
```

But it returns in `current_file` current window's title which is only file name without extension.
whereas I need a full path.

Can I get this done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you have a look inside VLC's dictionary in Skript-Editor? You find something like

```
tell application "VLC"
    log (get name of current item)
    log (get path of current item)
end tell
```

inside the VLC Suite.

Enjoy,
Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Alack, it returns "only file name without extension" too, not a full path. :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's my inattention. Second line in `tell` works perfectly. Thank you so much.